# GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\Connect Exception cURL error 52 empty reply from the server

Tags: laravel

Need help figuring out why I get the above error code when I run the command     `laravel new app-name` at the command prompt.

PS: connected to internet through a company proxy

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command instead of `laravel new your-app`:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-app --prefer-dist
```

But make sure your composer is updated first. Take a look at [this](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md).

edited:
Try the `laravel new your-app` command after your `composer update` again.

Comment: You can also update all globally installed composer package by `composer global update`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `composer global update` it should work